# How do I check if a username has been used and if it hasn't, enter the chosen username into a MySQL Database?

Tags: php, sql

I am making a registration system, and I wanted to check wether or not a Username chosen by the user has already been used and if it hasn't already been used, enter the chosen username into the DB?.

below is my query as it is so far, but I keep getting syntax errors. For the record: I am going to use BindParam() to bind the PHP input of the user into the query :)

I also have another column called "ID-number", which is a primary key.

Any help on how to do this is welcome!

Greets,

Romulus

---

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN `Username` != `Username`

THEN

INSERT INTO 'T_Users' `Username`, `Password`, `Email`
VALUES ':username', ':password', ':email'

END

FROM `T_Users`
```

Comment: Care to share the syntax error with us? 5 thousand alternatives http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+username+exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
<?php

$query = mysqli_query($con , "SELECT 1 FROM `T_Users` WHERE username = '$username'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
   echo "Username is already taken";
} else {
  # Username is available do insert the Data into Database ....
}



?>
```

Comment: This would work, but would be subject to race conditions - two people trying to register at the same time with the same username. Maybe unlikely in this situation? It's good practice to avoid things like this as the headaches they can cause in the future as no fun. Trust me, I've had my fair share :-/

Comment: Seems usefull, but where does the "1" stand for? Sorry if any of my questions seem stupid, I'm new to SQL and PHP;) @LukeCousins I dont think my site will be visited that often, it's on some remote corner of the interwebs;)

Comment: It doesn't matter what the `1` is, this solution is simply checking for a row (without bothering what is in the row). The race conditions might not be a problem in this case, but if you are ever working on a project that might have people trying to do something at the same time, it's worth bearing in mind.

Comment: @LukeCousins If two people submit a registeration form, with the same username, e-mail, and any other unique information, same computer, with the same internet connection: given that both transactions reach the DBMS simultaneously, the database concurrency control mechanism would guarantee isolation of the transactions, in effect choosing one transaction to precede the other. Given the unique constraint of the username, the second would be rejected. In other words, what Azi suggested is fine.

Comment: @Axel what is this unique constraint of the database that you refer to? I'm the only person to suggest a unique key, without that there is no such constraint. What does "same computer, with the same internet connection" have to do with it? Without a unique key on one or more fields (I'd suggest Username and maybe *another separate* key on Email), Azi answer would allow two people to register with the same details if they tried to do it in very quick succession.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest putting a unique key on the Username field and trying to do an insert. You can then catch the error and then can know that the user already exists. This is good as it isn't subject to race conditions (2 or more people trying to register at the same time with the same username and both successfully getting the same username).

Try something like:

```
if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `T_Users` (Username, Password, Email) VALUES('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx')") === TRUE){
    echo 'Welcome to the site!';
} else {
    echo 'Username taken';
}
```

Comment: And avoids the race condition where two people try to register with the same username at the same time.  It's a small possibility.